# Vue-router match query

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using vue-router and we are using alot of payload queries for example, **/Foo/?type=225**
How would i go about to match it to a nested component to the url in bold?

Something like this?

```
    const Foo = { template: '<div>Foo<router-view></router-view></div>' }
    const Bar = { template: '<div>Bar</div>' }

    const router = new VueRouter({
      mode: 'history',
      routes: [
        { 
          path: '/foo',
          component: Foo, 
          children: [
            {
              path: '',
              component: Bar,
              query: { type: '225' }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    })
```

The above code doesnt work properly, i want it to match just type=225 but it matches even type=1 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you to do that solution in your view file.

```
<Bar v-if="$route.query.type == 225" />
```